# Make an image fill up the cell completely

Tags: html, css

I want a image to fill up the table cell completely. with css i've set the padding to zero but it does not help. Anybody has any thoughts on this?

Greetz Job

```
.HTML

<div id="vakjes">
<table id="tabel" border="1">
<tr>
    <td><img class="" src="images/jack.png"></td>
    <td><img class="" src="images/jack.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img class="" src="images/jack.png"></td>
    <td><img class="" src="images/jack.png"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>


CSS

table, tr, td {
 border: 1px solid #FF7300;
 padding: 0px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

#tabel {
 width: 345px;
 height: 345px;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my table
http://i62.tinypic.com/1584fnb.png

Comment: Try adding `display:block` to the images.

Comment: have you tried setting your image width and height to 100%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the height and width of your image:

here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b5jsnrto/) where i've set:

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

Alernatively, if you didn't want all images to be set, you could create it as:

```
.myStyle{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

and then for your images add the class 'myStyle'.

Comment: Alright, this works better already but now are the images going over the border, that is also in your example :)

Comment: Adding Display: block; did fix this :-) thanks the problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are setting the width and height of the table in CSS #tabel?  Maybe the image is slightly smaller than the expected table size.  Try it without the #tabel CSS.